# pppd IP-UP script DIal out modem

Tags: linux

Need to dial out from PC to device having modem. device has Gadget serial. SO PC usb can be connected to usb of device and using driver can detect device as serial port. Now need to bypass dial out commands received over gadget serial port on device to modem connected via uart on device.

How can I configure pppd to do the same on the device via c++ code.

Comment: After reading your question for three times, still can't get what you are asking.. try to make it more clear.

Comment: Sorry about that.. checking if anyone has an idea abt the UP script in PPPD..wanted to dial out from a modem on another device (device is an embedded board connected to pc by usb). is ther a way to configure pppd on the device so that i can dial in from the pc..

Comment: So basically there is PC---Board---Modem? And where is pppd running - on PC or Board? Is there Linux or any other OS inside Board?

Comment: Linux inside board . PC could be Linux/ windows.. take linux for the time being ... ppd in both board, PC.

Comment: And what is the purpose of all this? Is PC going to use Internet provided by the Modem and receive data or it is just to set up and initiate connection (dial-out)?